# how to get the $q promise value on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, q

I'm using the `$q` from angularJS to get promises.

I would check the promise value in my controller to do some actions.

But I can not figure out how to get it to compare it.

This is how I do in my factory method :

```
AuthService.getActifUser = function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();
                if (cognitoUser) {
                     cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
                                if (err) {
                                        alert(err);
                                        deferred.reject('failed to login');
                                } else {
                                   deferred.resolve('logged in');
                                }
                                 });
                         } else {
                             deferred.reject('not logged in');
                }
                return deferred.promise;
        };
```

And this is how I try to get it in my controller :

```
var res = AuthService.getActifUser();
        console.log(res);
        if (res != 'logged in') {
            console.log(res);
            routeService.goToView('/pages/login')
        }
```

The log to `res` show me that :

```
Object { $$state: Object }
```

Someone knows how to do ?

Comment: Are you using any routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need to check res with if statement you can check like this:

```
var res = AuthService.getActifUser();

        res.then(function (response) {
            console.log("logged successfully");

        }, function (response) {
            routeService.goToView('/pages/login')
        });
```

first function for success result second for fail, angular will auto recognize result

Comment: Thanks dude it's perfect !

Answer (score 1):

res is a promise and should be resolved to get the data.

that state object you're logging is the state of the `promise` object.

```
res.then(function(resp){
 //succesful response
})
.catch(function(err){
 //exception happened
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`Object { $$state: Object }` shows because you're at the time your promise is still resolving.in controller catch the promise like this

```
AuthService.getActifUser().then(function(data){
        var res = data
        console.log(res);
        if (res != 'logged in') {
            console.log(res);
            routeService.goToView('/pages/login')
        }
});
```